# handle javascript array to use in google charts (flatten the days inside array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, charts

I have this array

```
[
  ["04/21/2021", 405, 85, 30]
  ["04/18/2021", 350, 135, 30]
  ["04/16/2021", 335, 120, 30]
  ["04/15/2021", 420, 100, 30]
  ["04/15/2021", 405, 85, 30]
  ["04/15/2021", 350, 135, 30]
  ["04/14/2021", 350, 135, 30]
  ["04/14/2021", 405, 85, 30]
  ["04/14/2021", 405, 85, 30]
]
```

I have no idea how to make it look like this

```
["04/21/2021", 405, 85, 30]
["04/18/2021", 350, 135, 30]
["04/16/2021", 335, 120, 30]
["04/15/2021", 1,595, 420, 120]
["04/14/2021", 1160, 305, 90]
```

I want to delete the repeat days and make them into one array before deleting them

Answer (score 0):

You can use "set" https://www.javascripttutorial.net/array/javascript-remove-duplicates-from-array/

Sry for not formating text I am writing this from my phone